# How to prove that $|\ln(1+x^4)) - \ln(1+y^4)| <= 3^\frac34|x-y| \space \forall \space x,y \in \mathbb R$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Question states

Prove that for all $x$ and $y$ $\in R$, the following inequality is true:

$\lvert \ln(1+x^4) - \ln(1+y^4)\rvert \le 3^\frac34\lvert x-y\rvert$

can you please solve this using mean value theorem? (it should be done this way)

Comment: Let try to apply MVT $f(x)-f(y)=f'(c)(x-y)$

Comment: i did it but i don't know, i'm stuck there

Comment: Are you sure that MVT need to be used?

Comment: 100%, even asked my teacher

Answer (score 2):

By Lagrange's theorem, it is enough to show that the derivative of $f(z)=\log(1+z^4)$ is bounded by the constant $3^{3/4}$. Indeed $|f'(z)|=\frac{4|z|^3}{1+z^4}\leq 3^{3/4}$ is a consequence of the AM-GM inequality:

$$|z|^3 = \frac{1}{3^{1/4}}\text{GM}(3,z^4,z^4,z^4)\leq \frac{1}{3^{1/4}}\text{AM}(3,z^4,z^4,z^4)=\frac{3^{3/4}}{4}(1+z^4). $$

Comment: Nice derivation!

Comment: This is genius.